# Solaris 10 - How do I check for IPv4-in-IPv6 mapping?

Tags: networking, solaris, ipv6, solaris-10

I was wondering if there is the equivalent of the following in Solaris for checking if IPV6_V6ONLY is enabled by default:

On a Linux system I can check if IPv6 only is enabled by checking the following file:

/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only

If bindv6only contains 0 (IPv4-in-IPv6 & IPv6 are both enabled).

If bindv6only contains 1 (Only IPv6 is enabled).

How can I check that IPV6_V6ONLY by default is enabled on Solaris 10 ? Is there one configuration parameter that can provide this info or do I need to iterate through interfaces via ifconfig -a6 or /etc/hostname6.xxx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris provides socket option defaults with the `ndd` command, e.g.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ndd /dev/ip \?
```

In this instance Solaris does not provide an option to allow the administrator to enable `IPV6_V6ONLY` by default.

You might enjoy this:

http://blog.caurea.org/2010/01/31/the-abomination-known-as-ipv6-v6only.html